# Namespace and class name appended to the end of the serialized xml stream

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

you know how it works, you handle a "Hello World" and your boss thinks you are ready for something bigger.

I am having a problem with C# and xml serialization. The xml is saved to file and the annoying bit is that i get the namespace.typename at the very end of the file.

```
namespace test123
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("MyTopClass", IsNullable=false)]

    public partial class MyTopClass {
        public MyMiddleClass DummyMiddle;
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MyMiddleArray")]
        public MyMiddleArray[] DummyMiddleArr;
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class MyMiddleClass {
        public MyLowerClass DummyLower;            
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class MyMiddleArray {
       public MyLowestClass DummyLowest;
       public MyLowesterClass DummyLowester;
    }

}
```

When i serialize one element of DummyMiddleArray i get the xml as expected, but at the very end, just beside the closing tag, i get the namespace and the classname

ie

```
</MyMiddleArray>test123.MyMiddleArray
```

I do i get rid of this small piece of text at the end?

I'd prefer to leave the class as it is, it has been developed ages ago and working like a charm ever since.

Thanks

EDIT 
Serialization + writing code

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyMiddleArray));
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml",true))
 {
     serializer.Serialize(writer, mndt);
     writer.Write(mndt);
     //writer.Flush();
     //writer.Close();
 }
```

While getting the hang of xmlserializer i read somewhere that woth "using" you do not need the flush and close. De-commenting the two lines of code does not change the output. What can it be?

Comment: Show you serialisation code... And the code you use to save to the file.

Comment: I think there is more data that is missing in the file.  I suspect you didn't flush your stream before the program ended.  Make sure you flush() and Close() the output file before your application stops.

Comment: serialization code in the message, pretty standard.

Comment: SOLVED!! :-) I do not need the writer.Write(nmdt). Commented that line and got the plain xml.